Pandas convert object type to array of strings
I have a pandas dataframe column with array of strings such as
["one", "two", "three"]["four", "five", "six"]
However when I print column datatype print(df['names'].dtype) it shows object. How do I convert it to data type array of strings?

Any specific reason you want to do that? For numeric data, a numeric dtype is usually the way to go, but for strings, object dtype actually has a lot of advantages over trying to use NumPy's string dtypes. Pandas uses object dtype for strings deliberately.

(And if you're saying individual dataframe cells contain lists of strings, and you want to convert that to some sort of "array of strings" dtype where every element is an array, that's not going to work at all.)

If you mean StringArray and StringDtype, you can create the dataframe specifying dtype='string', or use .astype('string'), as per the documentation.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["one", "two", "three"],
        "col2": ["four", "five", "six"],
    },
    dtype="string",
)

# or

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["one", "two", "three"],
        "col2": ["four", "five", "six"],
    },
)
df = df.astype('string')

For now these dtypes are experimental and the performance is the same as using dtype object.
